# Change default EXIF data

Tags: exif

Is there a way to change "hardcoded" default EXIF data when taking photos?

i.e I have Make 'LG Electronics', I want it to be 'Apple'

Model 'LG-D802', change it to 'iPhone X'

I know there are a lot of software that can change EXIF data *after* photo taken, what I'm looking for is a tweak that permanently changes selected EXIF tags at shooting time.